# CSS doesn't change in a permanent way

Tags: css, resize, overflow

Vague questions but i don't know the right question to ask google either.

I have a widget that has a background img that is in columns on my page. But when I resize the page my widget will be destroyed making impossible to scroll the page sideways. The background image is also cut off.

Also: how can I prepare for my page to adapt to different screen sizes? Is there a way to make my widget stick in one place? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

```
.example_wrapper
{
    margin: 10px 20% 10px 20%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
    height: 315px;

    border-radius: 20px;      
}

.example_container
{
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 3%;
    align: center;
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow:auto;      
    background-image: url('img.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.example_textarea
{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 145px 30% 0 5%;
    align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 130px;


}

.twitter_block
{
   position: left;
   margin: 6px;
   height: 120px;
   width: 120px;
   align: left;
   float: left;


}



.twitter_pic
{
    position: center;
    margin: 1px 20% auto 20%;

}

.scale-image
{
height:73px;
width: 73px;


}

.twitter_link
{
position: none;
margin: 0px 100px auto 30px;
}

.twitter_half
{
margin: 0px;


}

.twitter_profile_pos
{
text-align: center;
margin: 0px 10px auto 17px;
font-weight: bold;

}

.twitter_profile_pos a
{
color: #043E6B;

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code pertaining to the background image and your widget? It'll help everyone to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Posted. I forgot since im rushing to get this done and im not a css person which makes this frustrating. Thanks

Comment: The HTML might not be a bad idea to post either. Without it, we have no context to apply the CSS.

Comment: Or post the website where you are getting this.

Answer (score 0):

It could be some sort of clearing issue, or it could be something to with your position rules.

`position:none`, `position:left` and `position:center` are not valid rules. So those won't help with any positioning issues.

`position:absolute` might be breaking your layout if `position:relative` is not applied to the parent element (otherwise it positions the element *relative* to the whole document, rather than a specific element). This *could* be causing the break on resize.

If you could post your corresponding HTML, everyone should be able to recreate it. Or better yet, if you post the code on [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) and put the link here, we can help solve it even faster!!